# printf/fprintf maximum size according to c99

Tags: c, printf, c99

The C99 [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says:

> The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion
>   shall be at least 4095

Does it mean that the maximum size is 4095 if yes why its says "at least"?

Comment: It's the minimum number that *can* be produced, so it's the minimum maximum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've found one of the more annoying aspects of the C language specifications. They don't usually say what a maximum is. Instead, they'll usually say what the *smallest allowed value for a maximum* is.

They recognized that different hardware / compiler / linker environments have different restrictions, so they left most of the limits up to the individual tool authors. However, they wanted to provide *some* amount of portability between environments, so they specified the *lowest* values that *maximums* could take.

This is how we got restrictions like only the first 8 characters of identifiers being taken into account when disambiguating symbols -- they didn't want to force any implementor to deal with longer identifiers, so they said the "least maximum" length was 8.

It's the same story here -- they wanted programmers to be able to use decent-sized conversion, but recognized some platforms may not be able to handle *huge* conversions -- so they put in place a size large enough for most programmers to never know about the limit, but small enough that some implementations can do only the minimum and still be compliant.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing compilers must allow at least 4095 characters but more is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

"at least" means it is a minimum, not a maximum.

Implementations must support at least that much, but can support more.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard doesn't specify a maximum. What they do specify is the minimum value the maximum is allowed to be.