# Maximum size of string can be printed using %s?

Tags: c, linux, printf

What is the maximum size which can be printed using `%s` in c language.

I was trying to print a buffer in file using `fprintf` but at a point I felt that it was going more to 320KB . And `fprintf` was writing truncated string to the file . Is there any limit with `%s` ?

Comment: There is no limit, you should check that the string is a valid c string. Post some code please, may be we can help spot the problem.

Comment: I would imagine that in any implementation of `printf`, it just goes through the pointed string and sends one character at a time to the designated `FILE` pointer, until it encounters the null-character. That said, I doubt that the C-language standard specifies how `printf` should be implemented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`printf()` has an upper limit. It will successfully handle up to N `char`s.  N is at *least* 4095.

> The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least
>   4095.   C11dr §7.21.6.1 15

---

[Edit]

With such a large (320 kB) expected output, if possible, consider using `fputs(s, stream)` rather than `fprintf(stream, "%s", s);` which does not have this 4095 limitation.

Similar to
[printf/fprintf maximum size according to c99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119914/printf-fprintf-maximum-size-according-to-c99?rq=1)

Comment: *It was successfully handle up to N char*  what does this mean?

Comment: @chux Can you comment on any practical limits for any specific compilers?  GCC?  MSVC?

Comment: @Degustaf I am unfamiliar with GCC, MSVC compiler limits.

Comment: @chux didn't notice the update. I removed the comment. I upvoted your answer in the beginning.

Comment: @Degustaf I reviewed various GCC & MSVC documentation and did not find a limitation in those - maybe it exist - maybe not.   It is _possible_, no practical limitation exists for those compilers.  OP's situation may have stopped shy of 320K due to an embedded `'\0'` in the string.  IAC, `fputs()` is likely a good solution for OP.

Comment: @M.M Comment unclear as that is more about the compiler conversions and OP's concern is about run-time issues with `printf()` conversions.

Comment: In brief, it's not true that `printf` has a fixed upper limit, nor that it must handle at least 4095 chars

Comment: @M.M Disagree with [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800706/maximum-size-of-string-can-be-printed-using-s/27801006?noredirect=1#comment93718046_27801006).  I look forward to your answer's interpretation regarding the  "Environmental limits" of `fprint()`.

Comment: @chux OK, I agree with you more after reviewing the standard. `N` doesn't necessarily exist but this is just minor pedantry really