# Is there a length limit for fprintf?

Tags: c, linux

I have the following Ansi C code, running on Linux (version 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64):

```
    fprintf(fpOut, "%s",cBuffer);
```

Where cBuffer is a pointer to char, as in

```
    int bfnAddOutputFile(FILE *fpOut, char *cBuffer){/**/

        fprintf(fpOut, "%s",cBuffer);

        //code
        
        return ( TRUE );
    }
```

When it executes the `fprintf` statement, it generates a core dump.
[image: screenshot]

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x00000038b2e6723e in fputs () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Is there a maximum number of characters that can be sent to `fprintf`, and if yes what is the number?

Comment: is `cBuffer` ASCIIZ string?

Comment: It is unclear why are you crashing therefore why do you think it is a length problem?

Comment: Take a look to this related post [printf/fprintf maximum size according to c99](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119914/printf-fprintf-maximum-size-according-to-c99).

Comment: Your string is probably not terminated with a null byte. Replace `fprintf(fpOut, "%s",cBuffer);` with `printf("%zd\n",strlen(cBuffer));` and see if the error still happens.

Comment: Do you mean `strlen`, @squeamishossifrage?  If so, (1) `strlen()` would be likely to suffer from the same problem, and (2) the correct field descriptor would be `%zx`, not `%xd`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes. (Still got my Python hat on!)

Answer (score 3):

`cBuffer` probably doesn't contain a null-terminator, which makes `fprintf` go over the memory bounds.

While outputting a C-string, `printf`-family functions stop only when they encounter a *null-terminator* (`'\0'`) and can go on otherwise, until they try to output a piece of memory that *doesn't belong* to your program, which causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: Though not the OP's case, `[f|s]printf` can stop before encountering a string terminator if a field width is given.

Comment: The cBuffer was too small, so the null-terminator was not contain in the fprintf.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  Suspect you mean _precision_, not _field width_.

Comment: Right you are, @chux.  The `printf`-family functions will not output more characters of a string argument than the field *precision*, not width.  For example, one might use something like this: `fprintf(fpOut, "%.255s",cBuffer);`.